Non-elementary integral which becomes elementary through a geometric argument
I occasionally wonder about the following question when I teach the washer and shell methods in Calculus II.
Is there a real invertible function $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ with both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ being elementary functions such that one of

$f(x)^2$
$y f^{-1}(y)$

has an elementary antiderivative, but the other does not?
Note that 1) is more-or-less the integrand when finding the volume of the solid $S$ obtained by revolving $f$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ around the $x$-axis and 2) is more-or-less the integrand when finding the volume of $S$ via shells.
My feeling is that the answer is no for reasons involving the algebraic structure of spaces of functions having elementary antiderivatives, but I don't know much about this field.
If the answer is no, why not? And is there a different setting under which a geometric or physical "change of perspective" might make a non-elementary integral elementary?

Note that the simpler question "Does there exist an invertible function $f$ such that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are elementary and exactly one of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ has an elementary antiderivative?" has a negative answer since $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Perhaps I misunderstood your question but I think you can repeat a similar calculation as in your comment for the main question. Indeed, substituting $y=f(x)$ in the second integral, we get
$$
\int y f^{-1}(y) dy = \int f(x) x f’(x) dx = \frac12 x f(x)^2 - \frac12 \int f(x)^2 dx = \frac12 y^2 f^{-1}(y) - \frac12 F(f^{-1}(y)) + C,
$$
where $F(x)$ is antiderivative of $f(x)^2$. So if one of the two has elementary antiderivative, then the other does too.
